# Google Apps Script: Selecting a single column in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a function below that prints out data from a  google sheet to a google doc. Is there any way to alter this so it only prints out the data from **Column '1'** (Or **Column 'B'**)?

```
function saveAsDOC() {
  var fileName = "Announcements Test File";
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(fileName);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Generating file..', 'Status', 3);

  // Get the range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();

    // Announcements loop
    if (data.length > 1) { // Make sure data is longer than one character
      for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
        if(new Date(data[row][2]) <= new Date()) { // Check the date
          for (var col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            if(data[row][col]!=""){ // Make sure the data is not empty
              doc.appendParagraph(data[row][col]); // Append announcement
              doc.appendParagraph("") // Line break between announcements
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err); // show the error messages in the browser
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `col` variable from a variable to a constant value:

change:

```
[col]
```

to:

```
[2]
```

And see what happens.

Comment: This makes the column print 3 times.

Comment: Okay, so you know that.  Something is probably looping 3 times.  What?  There are two `for` loops.  Is the `data[row].length` 3?  Or the `data.length` 3?

Comment: data.length? I don't know

Comment: Because both for loops should only be checking if the row is longer than one character and not empty once.